# Regex matching characters and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that matches letters and special characters except these

> 0-9\d!@#$%^&*()_+-=?>

```
charcheck:function(val){
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z][^0-9\d!@#$%^&*()_+-=?></\|}{]+$/
  return (regex.test(val)) ? true : false;
}
```

I wanted to add these characters to that list [] but when I do it breaks it.
I have even tried ][ but that breaks also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters in a regular expression. You can use them as literals by escaping them:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][^0-9\d!@#$%^&*()_+\-=?><\/\\|}{\[\]]+$/
                                           ^ ^ as literal
                              ^ - (dash) also needs to be escaped
                                    ^ ^ did you intend for these to be literals?
```

Comment: there are a few other characters in there that need to be escaped as well, like the `?`

Comment: @Rooster the `?` is in a group so I think it's fine, I could be wrong though. `+` and `|` should be fine too. `-` might be a problem. I'm not sure about `^`.

Comment: ahhh, didn't know those didn't need to be escaped in a group. +1 for the useful info

Comment: I just noticed there are even more problems here. `/` also needs to be escaped because it the regexp delimiter. And the `[backslash]` before `|` is probably not intended as an escape, to use `[backslash]` as a literal escape it: `[backslash][backslash]`. - SO has a bug where you can't post a backslash in code formatting :(

Comment: so you just need a \ before the character to escape it. Is there a way to escape them all instead of using \ before them all.

Comment: I also tried using slash[slash] along with the other list and it's not working.